# How to get white color in PyQT

Tags: pyqt

the following instructions gets me rgb value in pyqt

```
c = result.pixel(x,y)
r = str(QtGui.qRed(c))
g = str(QtGui.qGreen(c))
b = str(QtGui.qBlue(c))
```

is there any way to get white value ?
for example: QtGui.qWhite(c) something ??

Comment: What would such a qWhite would be/do ? Is this lightness ? Is it smth else ?

Comment: it is for lightness

Answer (score 0):

```
QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(c).lightness()
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract from a QColor not just the light but also the hue and saturation you can use [getHsl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#getHsl):

```
>>> QColor(0,128,80).getHsl()
(157, 255, 64, 255)
```